# how to stop the sound playing automaticly of a video when i launch html file on my browser?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, html5-video

i'm starting to learn about html5 and i am trying to make a video player using jquery mobile. i have searched the code and i've found it. i put the video file in my root folder.  when i click the link "play", there is a pop up video and i can play the video using control buttons, but the problem is, when i try to launch my html file on my browser (mozilla firefox), the sound of the video play automaticly without video pop up even when i don't click the link "play", the sound still plays . please help me how to make the sound of the video just play when the video pop up, so it doesn't sound anymore when i launch my file to my browser at firts time. 
i use this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head> 

 <title></title> 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="utama" data-theme="a" >
  <div data-role="header"  >
    <h1>header</h1>
  </div>  
  <div data-role="content">
    <p></p>
 <br/>
 <a href="#dialog" data-rel="dialog">play </a>
  </div>  
  <div data-role="footer" >
    <h4> &copy </h4>
  </div>
</div>  
<div data-role="page" id="dialog">
  <div data-role="header"  >
    <h1>video</h1>
  </div>  
  <div data-role="content">
 
 <iframe id="player_1" src="abjad_a.mp4" width="540" height="304" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen=""></iframe>
 <a  data-rel="back"> back</a>

  </div>  
  <div data-role="footer" >
    <h4>&copy </h4>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of code. [Edit] your question to include the code.

Comment: thank you, i have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [HTML5 Video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

> Playing Videos in HTML
>   Before HTML5, a video could only be played in a browser with a plug-in (like flash).

The HTML5  element specifies a standard way to embed a video in a web page.

instead of iframe then you can customise you video player by javascript [HTML Audio/Video DOM Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp)

see snippet :

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("video_mute");

vid.muted = true;//mute video on window load

function enableMute() { 
    vid.muted = true;
} 

function disableMute() { 
    vid.muted = false;
} 

function checkMute() { 
    alert(vid.muted);
}
```

```html
<video width="400" id="video_mute" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<button onclick="enableMute()" type="button">Mute sound</button>
<button onclick="disableMute()" type="button">Enable sound</button>
<button onclick="checkMute()" type="button">Check muted status</button><br>

<p>Video courtesy of <a href="https://www.bigbuckbunny.org/" target="_blank">Big Buck Bunny</a>.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. i really appreciate it.

Comment: how if i use iframe? is there any way to stop the sound that play automaticly when i launch my file to browser?

Comment: yep there is, you can use [`HTMLIFrameElement.mute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/mute)

Comment: Thank you to help me again. To be honest, I do not know how to use the syntax. where should i put the syntax, if i use the launch video player syntax from the site: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup-iframe/#&ui-state=dialog